# Vimeo form upload is not redirecting to the url provided

Tags: java, tomcat, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to upload a Video to Vimeo form my apache tomcat server. I am using the form based upload and I am supplying a redirect URL. The problem is that the video is correctly uploaded on Vimeo but my redirect URL is never called. I am using this code:

```
        HttpClient httpClient = null;

        RequestConfig.Builder requestBuilder = RequestConfig.custom();
        requestBuilder = requestBuilder.setConnectTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
        requestBuilder = requestBuilder.setConnectionRequestTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        builder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestBuilder.build());
        httpClient = builder.build();

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(UPLOAD_POST_URL);

        StringEntity postingString = new StringEntity("{\"upload\" : {\"approach\" : \"post\",\"redirect_url\" : \""+redirectUrl+"\"}}");
        post.setEntity(postingString);
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        post.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken.trim());
        HttpResponse serverResponse = httpClient.execute(post);

        // get response
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader((serverResponse.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output = "";
        String content = "";
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            content += output;
        }

        System.out.println("Response 1: "+content);


        // parse the response to see if there was an error
        JsonElement elem = new JsonParser().parse(content);
        JsonObject object = elem.getAsJsonObject();

        if (object.has("error"))
            throw new Exception(object.get("error").getAsString());

        // POST request to upload the video from EFS
        String uploadLink = object.getAsJsonObject("upload").get("upload_link").getAsString();


        post = new HttpPost(uploadLink);

        MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        entityBuilder.addPart("file_data", new FileBody(new File(videoEFSPath)));
        post.setEntity(entityBuilder.build());

        post.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken.trim());
        serverResponse = httpClient.execute(post);

        br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader((serverResponse.getEntity().getContent())));

        output = "";
        content = "";
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            content += output;
        }

        System.out.println("Response 2: " +content);

        // parse the response to see if there was an error
        elem = new JsonParser().parse(content);
        object = elem.getAsJsonObject();

        if (object.has("error"))
            throw new Exception(object.get("error").getAsString());
```

No exception is thrown. The redirect URL that I am passing is "http:127.0.0.1:8080/uploadResult" What could be the issue?

Comment: Just want to verify - is the JSON for upload.approach and upload.redirect_url provided in the request body, or the request uri (as query params)? The supported method is to provide that metadata in the request body.

Comment: @TommyPenner I think it is in the request body given the content type that I set. Do you know how I can be sure about this?